# Regular expression - empty or a minimum of 6 characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, minimum

I want to use an ASP:RegularExpressionValidator to enforce a minimum character count (6) but only if the field is NOT empty.

Could anyone help me with the regex for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(?:.{6,}|)$
```